# Number of Trailing Zeros of Binomial Coefficient

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients, factorial

If $x+2=18181818...$ $n$ $digits$, find the number zeros at the end of ${x \choose x/2}$.
 I have tried using Legendre's formula for factorials, but I have got nowhere because of the strange value of $x$.

Comment: Did you try it for $n = 1,2,3,\ldots$? Did something interesting happen, something you might be able to prove?

Comment: did you look over the formula for the binomial coefficients it uses more than one factorial.

Comment: Well, $n$ cannot be odd as we want $x/2$ to be an integer

Comment: Yes, I know the formula for binomial coefficients. Legendre's formula can be modified to find the number of trailing zeros at the end of products and quotients of factorials.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that there is a nice answer to this question? For $2n$ digits, starting with $n=1$ I get  $1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 7, 7, 7, 10, 8, 10, 13, 18, 13, 14, 14, 13, 17$.

Answer (score 1):

We want to find how many Trailing zeros for $\binom{2n}{n}$.

First Write the binomial as factorials $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$

And apply Legendre formula for every term separately.

For $(2n)!$ there are $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \lfloor \frac{2n}{2^k} \rfloor $ $2$'s and  $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \lfloor \frac{2n}{5^k} \rfloor $ $5$'s

Now for $(n!)^2$ it have the same powers of primes as $n!$ but they are multiplied by $2$ (simple powers rule), so there are $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} 2\lfloor \frac{n}{2^k} \rfloor $ $2$'s and  $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} 2\lfloor \frac{n}{5^k} \rfloor $ $5$'s

So for the expression $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ there are $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \lfloor \frac{2n}{2^k} \rfloor-2 \lfloor \frac{n}{2^k} \rfloor $ $2$'s and  $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \lfloor \frac{2n}{5^k} \rfloor -2\lfloor \frac{n}{5^k} \rfloor$ $5$'s (powers in denominator are subtracted ,simple powers rule).

So $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} $ there are $Min(\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \lfloor \frac{2n}{2^k} \rfloor-2 \lfloor \frac{n}{2^k} \rfloor ,\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \lfloor \frac{2n}{5^k} \rfloor-2 \lfloor \frac{n}{5^k} \rfloor )$ Trailing Zeros,

Checked for first $1000$ numbers and its correct.

Comment: I do know this formula. Can you please solve for $n=x$?

Comment: This is a general solution, just substitute instead of $n$, what you want, or give me a clear way to know $x$ and i could run it on Python or Wolfram for you.

Comment: This question was given on an exam, where I didn't have access to Wolfram or Python. The value of $x$ is given in the question.